# excel vba formula with date compare in IF function within a formula

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

Let's say cell A1 is a Date: 23/06/2017

Now in excel if I put the following formula in cell B1:

```
=  IF(INT(C2)>INT(2/15/2017);"Year1";"Year2")
```

then it's working fine.

However, If I try to put it thought VBA coda as:-

```
Set sht1 = xWb.Sheets("ProcessedData")
sht1.Range("B1").Select
sht1.Range("B1").Formula = _
    "=IF(INT(A1)>INT(2/15/2017);""Year1"";""Year2"")"
```

It is giving me error 1004 (Object not found). I tried with CDate but I think, I am missing something here.

Can you please help me with this issue.

Comment: Just FYI, `INT(some_Date)` does nothing apart from remove the time portion from a date, and `INT(2/15/2017)` is the same as `INT(0.0037183936539415)` i.e. `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Excel is English oriented**, you are using `;` in your formula.

So either change your `;` to `,` inside your formula string, like:

```
sht2.Range("B1").Formula = "=IF(INT(A1)>INT(2/15/2017),""Year1"",""Year2"")"
```

Or, change `Formula` to `FormulaLocal` as in the following line:

```
sht2.Range("B1").FormulaLocal = "=IF(INT(A1)>INT(2/15/2017);""Year1"";""Year2"")"
```

---

**Note**: in the `Formula` line I think you meant to use `sht1` and not `sht2`, so it should be:

```
sht1.Range("B1").Formula = "=IF(INT(A1)>INT(2/15/2017),""Year1"",""Year2"")"
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear, but am guessing it should also be `sht1` instead of `sht2`.

Comment: @SJR i think you might be right, but I was'nt sure since the PO didn't share his entire code, nore what he is trying to achieve (i'll add it as anoth option)

Comment: Although what you write is technically correct based on what the OP asked, I would guess he really wants the argument to the `INT` function to be a date.  i.e.:  `Range("B1").Formula = "=IF(INT(A1)>INT(""2/15/2017""),""Year1"",""Year2"")"`